# Label in the tab is not visible using Sharpnado Tabs (.NET MAUI)

Tags: c#, android, tabs, maui

I can't see the label in each UnderlinedTabItem. When I change UnderlinedTabItem to BottomTabItem, then the app automatically adapts the new TabItem and then I can see the label. But when I refresh the app I can't see the text again. Then when I change BottomTabItem to UnderlinedTabItem, the text appears again. But again, when I leave the app and log in again, I can't see the text unless I manually change the code and switch between UnderlinedTabItem and BottomTabItem. All TabItem works like that like SegmentedTabItem does the same thing. I even tried with an Android Emulator but it does the same thing.

```
<tabs:TabHostView Grid.Row="1" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <tabs:UnderlinedTabItem Label="1" SelectedTabColor="#ffca73" UnselectedLabelColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="white"/>
            <tabs:UnderlinedTabItem Label="2" SelectedTabColor="#ffca73" UnselectedLabelColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="white"/>
            <tabs:UnderlinedTabItem Label="3" SelectedTabColor="#ffca73" UnselectedLabelColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="white"/>
</tabs:TabHostView>
```

This is what it looks like when I just start the app.
[image]

Then below picture is what it looks like when I change `UnderlinedTabItem` to BottomTabItem. It changes automatically and shows the label.
[image]

Then if I change `BottomTabItem` to `UnderlinedTabItem` it works well like below.
[image]

But then when I get out of the app and run it again, it disappears and goes back to the first picture.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just made a demo and found the similar issue.

And then I remove the Background color or set the BackgroundColor="Transparent", then it can show:

```
<tabs:UnderlinedTabItem Label="3" SelectedTabColor="#ffca73" UnselectedLabelColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
```

or

```
<tabs:UnderlinedTabItem Label="3" SelectedTabColor="#ffca73" UnselectedLabelColor="Gray" />
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Glad it woks! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

In my case did not work the accepted solution but I found a workaround by just adding the property UnderlineAllTab = false to all UnderlineAllTab items, for example:

```
<tabs:UnderlinedTabItem Label="3" SelectedTabColor="#ffca73" UnselectedLabelColor="Gray" UnderlineAllTab="False"/>
```